# Cargar un dato automático al cargar el valor

Tags: javascript, php

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    const inputFecha = document.querySelector("#fechaNac");
    const inputEdad = document.getElementById("edad");

    inputFecha.addEventListener('change', Edad);

    Edad();

    function Edad() {
        var fechaNacimiento = inputFecha.value;
        const fechaActual = new Date();
        const anoActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getFullYear());
        const mesActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getMonth()) + 1;
        const diaActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getDay());
        //01-01-2010  2010-01-01
        const anoNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(0, 4));
        const mesNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(5, 7));
        const diaNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(8, 10));

        let edad = anoActual - anoNacimiento;
        console.log(anoNacimiento);
        if (mesActual < mesNacimiento) {
            edad--;
        } else if (mesActual == mesNacimiento) {
            if (diaActual < diaNacimiento) {
                edad--;
            }
        }
        inputEdad.value = edad;
    }
});
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th hidden>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.idEntidad)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nombre)
            </th>           
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fechaConsulta)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbDatos">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th hidden>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.idEntidad)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.nombre)
                </th>               
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.fechaConsulta)
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a class="fa-solid fa-user-doctor fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" asp-controller="Consulta" asp-action="Atencion" asp-route-id="@item.idEntidad"></a>
                </th>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>


<form>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <input asp-for="idEntidad" class="form-control" type="hidden" id="idEntidad"/>
        <input asp-for="fechaNac" class="form-control" id="fechaNac" min="01-01-1930" type="hidden" />
        <div class="col-10">
            <label asp-for="nombre" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="edad" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="edad" class="form-control" id="edad" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

tengo una lista, en donde se cargan una lista de nombres desde una base de datos, esta lista tiene un botón que referencia al usuario por id, la cual me lleva a un formulario cargando los datos del usuario, como nombre,  fecha nacimiento y la edad se debe llenar automáticamente con la fecha de nacimiento. En el formulario el input donde se carga fecha de nacimiento y el id del usuario son de tipo hidden y por ese motivo la edad no se calcula. Lo probé quitando el hidden del input de fecha de nacimiento y calcula la edad sin problemas. Espero ahora me puedan entender

Comment: Te refieres a que si por ejemplo le pones un valor directo en el `value `al `input` así `<input asp-for="fechaNac" class="form-control" id="fechaNac" min="01-01-1930" oninput="Edad(this.value)" value="01-01-2000" /> ` no cambia la edad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función es llamada desde un `oninput`, significa que no se llamará mientras no escribas en el input. Si cuando el DOM se carga el `input` de la fecha de nacimiento viene ya con valores, puedes tomar ese valor y calcular la edad escuchando a [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) y también asignar un evento de escucha del tipo `onchange`, en caso de que el `input` sea editable.

Por cierto, evita las llamada in-line. Son una mala práctica. Como verás en el ejemplo, no necesitas de ellas.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const inputFecha = document.getElementById("fechaNac");
  const inputEdad = document.getElementById("edad");

  Edad();

  function Edad() {
    var fechaNacimiento = inputFecha.value;
    const fechaActual = new Date();
    const anoActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getFullYear());
    const mesActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getMonth()) + 1;
    const diaActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getDay());
    //01-01-2010  2010-01-01
    const anoNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(0, 4));
    const mesNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(5, 7));
    const diaNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(8, 10));

    let edad = anoActual - anoNacimiento;
    console.log(anoNacimiento);
    if (mesActual < mesNacimiento) {
      edad--;
    } else if (mesActual == mesNacimiento) {
      if (diaActual < diaNacimiento) {
        edad--;
      }
    }
    inputEdad.value = edad;
  }

});
```

```html
<input asp-for="fechaNac" class="form-control" id="fechaNac" min="01-01-1930" value="1980-01-01" />
<input asp-for="edad" class="form-control" id="edad" readonly />
```

Veamos un ejemplo escuchando además el evento `change` del `input`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const inputFecha = document.querySelector('#fechaNac');
  const inputEdad = document.getElementById("edad");

  inputFecha.addEventListener('change', Edad);

  Edad();

  function Edad() {
    var fechaNacimiento = inputFecha.value;
    const fechaActual = new Date();
    const anoActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getFullYear());
    const mesActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getMonth()) + 1;
    const diaActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getDay());
    //01-01-2010  2010-01-01
    const anoNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(0, 4));
    const mesNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(5, 7));
    const diaNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(8, 10));

    let edad = anoActual - anoNacimiento;
    console.log(anoNacimiento);
    if (mesActual < mesNacimiento) {
      edad--;
    } else if (mesActual == mesNacimiento) {
      if (diaActual < diaNacimiento) {
        edad--;
      }
    }
    inputEdad.value = edad;
  }
});
```

```html
<input asp-for="fechaNac" class="form-control" id="fechaNac" min="01-01-1930" value="1980-01-01" />
<input asp-for="edad" class="form-control" id="edad" readonly />
```

#### Edit

Con un input de tipo `hidden` también funciona:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const inputFecha = document.querySelector('#fechaNac');
  const inputEdad = document.getElementById("edad");

  // inputFecha.addEventListener('change', Edad);

  Edad();

  function Edad() {
    var fechaNacimiento = inputFecha.value;
    const fechaActual = new Date();
    const anoActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getFullYear());
    const mesActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getMonth()) + 1;
    const diaActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getDay());
    //01-01-2010  2010-01-01
    const anoNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(0, 4));
    const mesNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(5, 7));
    const diaNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(8, 10));

    let edad = anoActual - anoNacimiento;
    console.log(anoNacimiento);
    if (mesActual < mesNacimiento) {
      edad--;
    } else if (mesActual == mesNacimiento) {
      if (diaActual < diaNacimiento) {
        edad--;
      }
    }
    inputEdad.value = edad;
  }
});
```

```html
<input asp-for="fechaNac" class="form-control" id="fechaNac" min="01-01-1930" value="1980-01-01" type="hidden" />
<input asp-for="edad" class="form-control" id="edad" readonly />
```

Comment: muchas gracias, era justo lo q necesitaba y tomare en cuenta lo de las llamadas in-line. Gracias

Comment: Una consulta, el codigo funciona corectamente me muestra la edad y todo bien, pero si pongo el input de fechaNac como type="hidden", ya no calcula la edad, xq???

Comment: @jano sí funciona, revisa el último fragmento de código.

Comment: @jano sin ver el escenario real es difícil reproducir el problema. ¿Podrías agregar en la pregunta un código con ese escenario que dices o, si es un problema nuevo, abrir una nueva pregunta con el nuevo problema? Sería cuestión de lanzar el código desde ese evento en el cual se llenan los datos, no hay más misterio. Puede que no estés refiriendo bien al elemento en ese nuevo contexto, o que no esté cargado cuando intentas acceder a él.

Comment: @jano no me queda claro cuál es el elemento que dispara el código para que se calcule la edad. Hablas de un botón o algo así, pero ¿cuál es ese botón en tu código o cual es ese elemento y qué acción ocurre en él para que se dispare el código del cálculo de la edad? Eso no lo veo claro, ni en el código ni en el planteamiento de la pregunta y eso es lo fundamental para saber por qué no funciona o incluso para simplificar el código.

Comment: @jano en las preguntas es importante siempre ser los más claros posibles explicando el contexto. Por ejemplo: en la pregunta original hablabas de un input, pero ahora parece que son varios inputs ¿? Pues bien, eso cambia todo el panorama, porque podríamos estar hablando de asignar escucha por una clase (para alcanzar `N` elementos de una clase) y no por un id (que alcanza un sólo elemento). Digo esto porque podrías estar complicando el código, cuando las cosas pueden ser más simples. Pero sin entender bien el contexto es más difícil dar una respuesta más óptima. Lo digo también para el futuro.

Comment: Bueno, yo tengo que cargar los datos en un formulario(nombre, id, fecha de nacimiento), nada se ingresa manual. La edad se calcula cuando se carga la fecha de nacimiento , con la funcion Edad(). El problema es que si el input de fecha de nacimiento esta oculto (type="hidden") la edad no se calcula. Disculpen las molestias si no fui claro anteriormente, espero puedan ayudarme.